# CSS Transform Scale cuts off content from wrapper

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I have a wrapper container with a fixed height and width, and is set to `overflow: scroll`. Inside, I have a bunch of other content that is accessible by scrolling around to it.

I also have a zoom-in and zoom-out button. The buttons apply a `transform: scale(x)` to the content, which seems to work just fine. I've set the `transform-origin` to be the centre of what's visible in the wrapper by checking the wrapper's `scrollTop` value.

My issue, however, is that when the content is zoomed in on, it is cut off by the wrapper (expected) but is inaccessible by scrolling (unexpected).

I've created an example of my issue with a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fw43qrbj/), and will also post the code here:

```js
let zoom = 1;

function fnZoom(zoomModifier) {
    zoom += zoomModifier;
    let scrollTop = document.getElementById("a").scrollTop;
    document.getElementById("b").style.transformOrigin = `150px ${scrollTop + 100}px`;
   document.getElementById("b").style.transform = `scale(${zoom})`;
}
```

```css
#a {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#b {
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20000px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
#c {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="a">
    <div id="b">
      Test
      <p id="c">
        middle
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="fnZoom(0.1)">zoom-in</button>
  <button onclick="fnZoom(-0.1)">zoom-out</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that if you click on the zoom-in button, it will zoom the content correctly, but the cut-off portion of the content is inaccessible by scrolling.

Is there any way to fix this so that the content can be scrolled to?

A couple things to note:

- Cannot use jQuery
- Would prefer CSS-based solutions of JavaScript solutions, but will accept either that works

Comment: That's entirely expected. A `transform`is **entirely visual**...its not actually changing the size of the element.

Comment: @Paulie_D is there maybe another property that can achieve what transform does visually and actually mutates the element?

Comment: Only **actually** changing the dimensions of the element.